Spring Boot application auto restarts every 15 minutes for unknown reasons
I have an issue with my Spring Boot application: somehow it restarts automatically every 15 minutes.
I removed devtool in pom.xml but that didn't solve the problem. I don't use ShutdownHook either.
I am using Spring Boot 2.7.14 with the following dependencies:

starter-actuator
data-jdbc data-jpa
web-service
starter-openfeign
wsdl4j jpos
lombok
springdoc-openapi-ui
jasypt-spring-boot-starter

And log:
2024-Apr-10 07:15:01.170 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-Apr-10 07:15:01.175 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-Apr-10 07:15:01.214 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:09.194 INFO  [main] h.a.T2tAdapterApplication - Starting T2tAdapterApplication v1.0.1 using Java 1.8.0_212 on T2TAdapter with PID 103349 (/opt/t2t/t2t-adapter-v2-1.0.0.jar started by root in /opt/t2t)
2024-Apr-10 07:15:09.196 INFO  [main] h.a.T2tAdapterApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.263 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.265 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.284 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.298 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.312 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.321 INFO  [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.598 INFO  [main] o.s.c.c.s.GenericScope - BeanFactory id=460aeb77-e91f-3cb1-99fe-ad862db90893
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.684 INFO  [main] c.u.j.c.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor - Post-processing PropertySource instances
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.776 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource configurationProperties [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource] to AOP Proxy
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.779 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.779 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource cachedrandom [org.springframework.cloud.util.random.CachedRandomPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource springCloudClientHostInfo [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource Config resource 'file [config/application.properties]' via location 'optional:file:./config/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.780 INFO  [main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter - Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.894 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb67ccdd] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.971 INFO  [main] o.s.w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping - Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2024-Apr-10 07:15:11.985 INFO  [main] c.u.j.f.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter - Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.215 INFO  [main] c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver - Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.221 INFO  [main] c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector - Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.596 INFO  [main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.651 INFO  [main] o.a.c.c.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.652 INFO  [main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.78]
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.754 INFO  [main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.754 INFO  [main] o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3469 ms
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.927 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - String Encryptor custom Bean not found with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'. Initializing Default String Encryptor
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.948 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.keyObtentionIterations, using default value: 1000
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.949 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.poolSize, using default value: 1
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.949 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.providerName, using default value: null
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.949 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.providerClassName, using default value: null
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.949 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.saltGeneratorClassname, using default value: org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator
2024-Apr-10 07:15:12.951 INFO  [main] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor - Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.stringOutputType, using default value: base64
2024-Apr-10 07:15:13.853 INFO  [main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-Apr-10 07:15:13.996 INFO  [main] o.h.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
2024-Apr-10 07:15:14.471 INFO  [main] o.h.a.c.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2024-Apr-10 07:15:14.755 INFO  [main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-Apr-10 07:15:14.761 WARN  [main] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:15.767 INFO  [main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-Apr-10 07:15:15.823 INFO  [main] o.h.d.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2024-Apr-10 07:15:16.792 INFO  [main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2024-Apr-10 07:15:16.834 INFO  [main] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-Apr-10 07:15:17.918 WARN  [main] o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-Apr-10 07:15:20.425 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.e.w.EndpointLinksResolver - Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-Apr-10 07:15:20.519 INFO  [main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''


Don't use quote format for logs, it is unreadable. Use multi line code formats.

That log is mostly the startup log, with just the last few lines of the shutdown, Please add the previous lines.

You need to provide some more context. Is it restarting also when running on your PC through your IDE? Is it restarting when running on a hosted platform or Kubernetes cluster? Maybe its getting killed by the host because some health check is failing? The logs are pretty much useless, you are only showing it starting up.

I solved my problem, because the crontab was set to restart the service every 15 minutes :( . Thank you

Please add this to the application and inspect the output:
@Component
public class RefreshListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received spring refresh event - " 
                         + event.getMessage() + event);
    }
}

You will find who and maybe why the context is refreshing.
